# How do superior successes work in Eclipse Phase 2?

Tags: eclipse-phase

Re-reading the rules for Eclipse Phase 2, in preparation for a game that I'll be running for a group that is entirely new to Eclipse Phase, I saw this:

> "*If a critical is also a superior result, only the critical applies.*" p. 31 EP2

Since critical results occur when a character rolls doubles (e.g. 00, 11, 22, etc.) on a test, and superior results are scored on either a 33 or 66, this means that superior results are only **ever** scored on a critical.

Given the above, it seems like RAW you can actually never score superior results.

Is this an accurate reading of the rules? It doesn't seem like this is what the designers intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> superior results are scored on either a 33 or 66

That's the mistake. It's not either 33 or 66, its **33 or more** or **66 or more**.
From EP2 book, p33:

> On a roll of 33 or more that succeeds, you get a superior success. On a roll of 66 or more, you get two superior successes. On a roll of 66 or less that fails, you get a superior failure. On a roll of 33 or less, you get two superior failures.

So if you succeed a test with 42, it's not a critical success, but it is 1 superior success. If it was 44 and still a success, it would be 1 superior critical success. If it was 77  and still a success it would be 2 superior critical successes.

Comment: It's worth noting that a superior critical success is *usually* the same as a critical success that is not superior. That's what the quoted line in the question is about. Only one roll cares about both at the same time, as far as I know: The roll to hack into a system (where critical success makes you more hidden, while superior successes upgrade your account access level).

Comment: Thanks, I missed the "or more" when reading this just now.